# "Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases" when doing 2-way repeated measures anova test

Tags: r, anova

I've been trying to run a 2-Way repeated measures test on a dataset, with year & vaccine type being the independent variables and coverage being a dependent variable. I ran it with the code:

```
sat = anova_test(
  data=SA, dv = coverage, wid = country, 
  within=c(vaccine, year)
)
```

but then I got the error

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

I've run `all(is.na())` on all variables, and all of them have turned up false, so there shouldn't be any NA cases. Coverage is definitely a numeric, while country, vaccine, year are definitely factors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:
I used the anova_test function from the package rstatix
Here's a summary of the data

```
> summary(SA)  
 unicef_region          iso3                  country    vaccine         year     
 Length:1360        Length:1360        Afghanistan:170   BCG :272   1985   :  40  
 Class :character   Class :character   Bangladesh :170   DTP1:272   1986   :  40  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Bhutan     :170   DTP3:272   1987   :  40  
                                       India      :170   MCV1:272   1988   :  40  
                                       Maldives   :170   POL3:272   1989   :  40  
                                       Nepal      :170              1990   :  40  
                                       (Other)    :340              (Other):1120  
    coverage        decade              logitv       
 Min.   : 1.00   Length:1360        Min.   :-4.5951  
 1st Qu.:63.00   Class :character   1st Qu.: 0.5322  
 Median :83.00   Mode  :character   Median : 1.5856  
 Mean   :75.97                      Mean   : 1.7595  
 3rd Qu.:96.00                      3rd Qu.: 3.1781  
 Max.   :99.00                      Max.   : 4.5951  

> head(SA)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  unicef_region iso3  country     vaccine year  coverage decade logitv
  <chr>         <chr> <fct>       <fct>   <fct>    <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
1 South Asia    AFG   Afghanistan BCG     1985        17 80s    -1.59 
2 South Asia    BGD   Bangladesh  BCG     1985         2 80s    -3.89 
3 South Asia    BTN   Bhutan      BCG     1985        54 80s     0.160
4 South Asia    IND   India       BCG     1985         8 80s    -2.44 
5 South Asia    MDV   Maldives    BCG     1985        45 80s    -0.201
6 South Asia    NPL   Nepal       BCG     1985        67 80s     0.708
```

Comment: (1) what package is `anova_test()` from (I don't think it's in base R)? (2) can we have a [mcve] please? Otherwise this is going to be a frustrating guessing game ... (at the very least, show us the output of `summary(SA)`)

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, I added a summary of the output and some example of data. Would this be more helpful?

Comment: I suspect the problem comes because of the different numbers of elements in the category of country. Please try repeating the analysis removing all data that correspond to country: (Other).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the formula interface, that worked for me.

```
sat = anova_test(
  data = SA, 
  coverage ~ vaccine * year,
  wid = country
)
```